# Error 500 al hacer deploy de Node.js en Azure

Tags: nodejs, azure, deployment

Estoy usando Azure para estudiantes e hice un deploy de una aplicación de Node.js, pero al tratar de acceder al dominio me sale el error 500.1002, la verdad es mi primera vez haciendo deploy y no sé bien qué onda, no se si sea el puerto, si es porque todavía no conecto la base de datos, si tengo mal el archivo web.config o qué, este es el código de mi archivo principal que se llama index.js

```javascript
//zona de imports
import conexion from "./conexiondb.js";
import app from "./app.js";

const port = 8000 //Definimos el puerto en el cual escuchará nuestro servidor

//Abrimos la conexión a la base de datos
conexion.connect((error) => {
    //Iniciamos el servidor
    if (!error) {
        app.listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`Servidor escuchando en http://localhost:${port}`)
            console.log('Conexión exitosa')
        })
    } else {
        console.error(error)
    }
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send('Hola mundo')
})
```

Este es el archivo web.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^index.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js" />
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"></httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Y esta es la pantalla de error que me sale al entrar al dominio:
[image: Pantalla de error 500 en azure]

Alguien tiene una idea de cuál puede ser el error y cómo lo resuelvo?